# Полоска для управления iPhone наезжает на fixed-блок в браузере

Tags: javascript, html, css

Вижу вот такую картину на своём сайте:

[image: Полоска наезжает на блок]

Возникла идея добавлять блоку border-bottom, когда полоска айфона отображается. Подскажите, как можно детектить состояние этой полоски? Может есть js-библиотека какая-нибудь?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для данной полоски и моноброви в css есть `safe-area-inset-top`, и `safe-area-inset-bottom`(а ещё `safe-area-inset-left` и `safe-area-inset-right`).

В коде это буде выглядеть как-то так:

```
.bottom_line_selector {
    /* второе значение будет взято если safe-area-inset-bottom отсуствует */
    padding: env(safe-area-inset-bottom, 5px);
}
```

[env() - css | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/env())